# Amazon MWS API Request Reports Error

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am trying to retrieve an Order Report via the MWS API.  To do this I have to submit a report request.  No matter how I prepare the request I am getting the same error:

```
The service cannot handle the request. Request is invalid.
```

I am using the Amazon Client Library. tis is the code we are using to make the call:

```
public InvokeSubmitReportResponse InvokeSubmitOrderReportRequest(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{

    RequestReportRequest callrequest = new RequestReportRequest();
    RequestReportResponse callresponse = new RequestReportResponse();
    InvokeSubmitReportResponse response = new InvokeSubmitReportResponse();
    callrequest.Merchant = sellerId;
    callrequest.MarketplaceIdList = new IdList();
    callrequest.MarketplaceIdList.Id = new List<string>(new string[] { marketPlaceId });
    callrequest.StartDate = startDate;
    callrequest.EndDate = endDate;
    callrequest.ReportType = "_GET_ORDERS_DATA_";

    try
    {
        callresponse = service.RequestReport(callrequest);
        response.CallStatus = true;
        response.EndDate = callresponse.RequestReportResult.ReportRequestInfo.EndDate;
        response.ReportProcessingStatus = callresponse.RequestReportResult.ReportRequestInfo.ReportProcessingStatus;
        response.ReportRequestId = callresponse.RequestReportResult.ReportRequestInfo.ReportRequestId;
        response.ReportType = callresponse.RequestReportResult.ReportRequestInfo.ReportType;
        response.Scheduled = callresponse.RequestReportResult.ReportRequestInfo.Scheduled;
        response.StartDate = callresponse.RequestReportResult.ReportRequestInfo.StartDate;
        response.SubmittedDate = callresponse.RequestReportResult.ReportRequestInfo.SubmittedDate;


    }
    catch (MarketplaceWebServiceException ex)
    {
        response.CallStatus = false;
        response.Error = ex;
    }

    return response;
}
```

In [this](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_RequestReport.html) documentation it tells me that the only required parameter is `ReportType`.  If I comment out all the other parameters in the request I get a `SellerId is required` error.  If I submit a request with just the `ReportType` and `Merchant` I get the `The service cannot handle the request. Request is invalid.` error, as I do if I pass all the paramters I want to pass.  I have checked the account identifying parameters and they are all correct.

Can anyone advise what the problem could be?

**Update**

I get the same error when using the Amazon scratchpad so I am assuming its a bug on their side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_GET_ORDERS_DATA_` is also known as "Scheduled XML Order Report". I haven't tried, but I believe you cannot request a report of that type. Scheduled reports are meant to be used with the [ManageReportSchedule](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ManageReportSchedule.html) call, which will let you create such a schedule. Further processing of such a report (GetReport calls etc.) is the same as with requested reports.

Comment: I submitted a ticket to Amazon in the end and you are right, it is a "Unrequestable" report.  I ended up using `_GET_CONVERGED_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_` which does all I need.